# query with float works only till 9.99 - flask api

Tags: python, api, flask

I have a column "price" in my API

```
price = db.Column(db.Float)
```

I like to query this price:

```
def get(self, id, aPrice, bPrice):

        meal = MealModel.query.filter(MealModel.category.has(id=id)).all()

        if meal:
            return[meal.json() for meal in MealModel.query.filter(MealModel.category.has(id=id), MealModel.price >= aPrice, MealModel.price <= bPrice).all() ]

        return{'message': 'mealId not found'}, 404
```

with this routing:

```
api.add_resource(MealbyCat, '/meal/category/<int:id>/<float:aPrice>/<float:bPrice>')
```

It works till bPrice=9.99 absolutely right

With a bPrice=10.0 I get only meals with a price till 1.99
with 20.0 till 2.99.. and so on...

same behavior with 100.0

Why does such behavior occur? And how can I slove that?

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess your `MealModel.price`, `aPrice`, `MealModel.price` and `bPrice` are strings. When comparing strings, "2.5" > "20" etc. Try

```
 return[meal.json() for meal in MealModel.query.filter(MealModel.category.has(id=id), float(MealModel.price) >= float(aPrice), float(MealModel.price) <= float(bPrice)).all()
```

If it works, consider placing `float()` in a better place.

Comment: Thanks, but float(MealMode.price) gives me a TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'InstrumentedAttribute' - I thought they are already float through declaration in Model and routing? - But I am really new in programming...

Comment: I guess you are the only one knowing what is MealModel and it's price. If you don't, than i guess you'd better start with that.

Comment: yeah you see in my post price is Float, and aPrice/bPrice too.. and float(MealModel.price) gives me a  TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'InstrumentedAttribute'